# sharepoint event handler data deleted when check in

Tags: sharepoint, checkin, eventreceiver

I'm writing an eventHandler to auto add a string when a file is added to a doclib.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = new SPSite("url");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("myWebSite");
    SPList list = web.Lists["DocCompteur"];

    string num = "000", chaine = "";
    int compteur = 0;
    SPListItem item = list.Items[0];
    num = item["compteur"].ToString();
    compteur = int.Parse(num);
    compteur++;
    chaine = compteur.ToString("000");
    item["compteur"] = chaine;
    item.Update();
    properties.AfterProperties["DocNumber"] = "pv" + chaine;
    //properties.ListItem.File.CheckIn("Automatic checkIn");
}
```

The problem is that when I add a file, I have to check in new information. If I check in, the string disappear. If I cancel, the string stay... 
With an image, I don't have that problem...

What's wrong with my eventHandler?

Comment: Is the DocNumber field shown on your edit item screen (which is shown as part of the Check-In dialog)? Is so is it properly populated? When you use an image is it in the same document library? Is it using the same content type?

Comment: Yes, the DocNumber field is shown on the edit item screen and correctly filled ( as you can see here http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/7597/qckh.png ). And yes, with an image it's in the same document library, nothing changing if it's a document or an image